# TS Is it possible to loop through keys of a type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to loop over a type definition?

A simple type like:

```
interface Budget {
      bills: number;
      transportation: number;
}
```

And then something like:

```
Object.keys(Budget).map((item) => etc...)
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, is something like this possible? So that I don't have to create an object of type Budget whenever I want to utilize built in functions?

Comment: can you include some transforming rules? Some test cases

Comment: I had the same question recently. Every `class` (even `abstract`) exists in runtime, and every class has a prototype. So, I thought about iterating over prototype's keys. Surprisingly, they weren't enumerable.

Comment: OP is asking about TypeScript which means, we're talking about compile time, not runtime, since there is no TS at runtime. Not sure though what exactly is meant by *looping over type definition*, but hopefully it's clear that at runtime we certainly can't loop through TS definitions like we can with Reflection in C# or Java.

Comment: Iterating through values of an iterable type, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Mathew can you please answer the question that I've asked in my comment

Comment: @wonderflame sorry I wasn't sure what you mean by transforming rules

Comment: include some input type and output type that you want

Comment: Given an non-nested type T with key,value pairs, return all keys of T as string[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Types are removed by the transpiler before runtime. In your case, the `Budget` reference will be undefined as no object named `Budget` exists in the transpiled code which is actually executed.

Comment: well, it may not be possible to do with js code, however, it is possible to generate a new type by transforming it (depending on the complexity of transform)